# The meaning of "sich etwas (dative) anschließen"

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

I had a few questions about the meaning of "sich etwas (dative) anschließen". It seems that there is many similar, but distinct meanings of this word that I'm struggling to get a good feeling for. Let me give some examples:

1. > Ich sehe eine Gruppe Freunde. Ich werde sie fragen, ob ich mich ihnen anschließen darf.

   I see a group of friends. I will ask them if I am allowed to join.
2. > Der Mann schloß sich der politischen Partei an.
3. > Der man schließt sich der Ideologie der Partei an.
4. > Ich schließe mich dir an.

   (I agree with you?)

Now, example 1 would suggest that "sich anschließen" simply means "join". This is consistent with example 2. However, "join" does not work anymore for examples 3 and 4, and hence I suspect that this does not simply mean "to join".

Is there a fundamental difference in the use of the word when we are talking about organizations and ideas? Or is there actually some common theme between the uses in 1,2, and 3,4?

Comment: It also means *to follow* or *to concur*.

Comment: @Janka thanks! So, when somebody says, "Ich schließe mich der Partei an", is there a common understanding of whether I am joining the party, or if I just agree with their ideas?

Comment: You need much more context to decide on this.

Comment: I do not think that 3 works very well.

Comment: @CarstenS I found this on the internet:

"Diese Leute haben nicht für den IS gekämpft . sie sind einzelne Personen letztlich die sich der Ideologie anschließen"

Is this not used correctly?

Comment: I was wrong, it sounded it bit off to me when described abstractly, but.when I think of examples, it can be used with ideologies or religions.

Comment: @CarstenS Thanks. Would you say that this is exactly equivalent to, "einer Ideologie folgen"?  Aber man würde "folgen" im vierten Beispiel nicht benutzen... oder?

Comment: It really all means *to join*, just sometimes figuratively. (Of course I do not claim that you could always actually use *join* in English for it.)

Comment: @CarstenS Thank you for your help. If I may ask one more question: Are expressions 1 and 4 normal use? If I see friends playing a game, can I say "Darf ich mich euch anschließen?=May I join (in playing)?" Also, if you make some random comment that I agree with, can I simply say, "Ich schließe mich dir an" instead of "Ich stmme dir zu?"

Comment: Don't try to understand the meaning of words or phrases in one language by translating them into another language. This works only is some special cases. Try to learn how to use them **in their own language**. If you want to learn German you must **think in German.** English is a foreign language to me. When I listen to someone talking in English, when I read English texts, when I speak English and when I write in English I always *think* in English. Otherwise it wouldn't work. I still make many mistakes, but my English would be way worse if I tried to translate  everything.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Thank you for the advice. I try to do that as much as possible, but I find it difficult not living in the country and never having the opportunity to speak with native speakers. Therefore, I try to somehow figure out these things by asking questions. I do agree with you though that direct translations are often not the best way.

Answer (score 5):

"Sich jdm./etw. anschließen" basically has three meanings. The boundaries between them are fluid.

### 1. join sb./sth.

Examples:

> Ich sehe eine Gruppe Freunde. Ich werde sie fragen, ob ich mich ihnen **anschließen** darf. – I see a group of friends. I will ask them if I am allowed to **join**.
>
> Ich habe mich kürzlich mehreren Vereinen **angeschlossen**. – I have recently **joined** several clubs.
>
> Ich habe einen Mitgliedsbeitrag gezahlt, um mich dem Golfclub **anzuschließen**. – I paid a membership fee to **join** the golf club.

### 2. associate oneself with sb./sth.

Examples:

> Der Mann **schloss** sich einer politischen Partei **an**. – The man **associated himself with** a political party.
>
> Ich **schließe** mich dieser Aussage **an**. – I **associate myself with** this statement. (I agree/concur with this statement.)
>
> Ich **schließe** mich dir **an**. – I **associate myself with** you. (I agree with you/I have the same opinion as you.)

### 3. follow sb./sth.

Examples:

> Der Mann **schließt** sich der Ideologie der Partei **an**. – The man **follows** the ideology of the party.
>
> Wir **schlossen** uns den anderen **an**, weil sie den Weg kannten. – We **followed** the others because they knew where to go.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! The only thing I have a question about is number 2. When you say, "associate with", do you mean, "agree with", or "identify with"? When I head, "I associate myself with a group", I hear, "I identify myself with". But in this case, "Ich schließe mich dieser Aussage an" is a little odd. What exactly do you mean with "associate with" here. Thanks again for your fantastic help!

Comment: @Mark I have added some more explanation. I basically mean "agree" or "concur". "Identify" is to overstated in my opinion. Please pay particular attention to *Hubert Schölnast*'s comment.